# R freezes in Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: r, macos, freeze

I encountered this problem and there was no clear explanation about how to work around this bug.

The latest version of R (v. 3.1.2) for OS X Mavericks freezes in Yosemite whenever I try to save a file which is written using R's internal editor. It also freezes when you try to `source` a function.

**Edit:** This was supposed to be a self-answered question, but I found a better answer, so I marked that as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run into the same problem.  I haven't tried Metallica's answer but found the problem has 95% disappeared after installing the latest "patch" version of R , as found at [att.com](http://r.research.att.com/) .

Comment: I just got a computer today, and downloaded the current version of R, which presumably would include these fixes if the bug is half a year old, and this did not work.

Comment: @MHH  please post a note to the r-sig-mac mailing list with a complete description of your OS version,  R version, and exactly what your command sequence was when the hang occurred.

Comment: I've been having this same issue for months using the file.choose() command and the change working directory menu under the "Misc" tab. I've used multiple Macs, all with the latest version of R. I posted about this but go no answer here : https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-April/428037.html

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is a bug in R's GUI. Some OS X features/libraries that used to be in place in earlier versions of OS X have been removed in Yosemite.

You can work around this bug by **running R from the terminal** / command line. Fire up the terminal app (quickest way is to use Spotlight search: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> -> `terminal`), and type in (or paste) the following command:

```
/Applications/R.app/Contents/MacOS/R
```

Also avoid using the `Misc` menu or other GUI elements if you can. Using the `change working directory` menu entry in the `Misc` menu causes a freeze. You can use the R command `setwd()` instead, e.g.:

```
setwd("path/to/your/working/directory")
```

There is a problem though, you have to change your working directory every time you open up R. To make the change permanent, put the above command (setwd) in your R's init file (`.Rprofile`) in your home directory. If you cannot find `.Rprofile`, that is fine, create a file in your home directory, name it `.Rprofile`, and paste the command there. This file is executed by R every time you open up R.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version (Wooden Christmas Tree 3.2.3 and the GUI 1.66) that were released on December 10, 2015 appear to have corrected this problem.  It does require you have Maverick or newer OS.  I've only performed limited trials, including opening with the GUI rather than through terminal, and have not had any hangs.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm running Wooden Christmas Tree on OSX El Capitan, and upgrading to the Christmas Tree version didn't help the problem.  When I click on the "source" button, I just get the rainbow carousel and the program becomes unresponsive.  Although I appreciate the suggestion to use the command line, it would be helpful to be able to use the GUI too.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone here with version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle" and running Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.6 with the same problem, I find that I can usually save an image I create if I save it in the current working directory. However, if you need to save an image in a specific location and the GUI freezes up, try the following command (for pdf images):

```
pdf(/path/to/location/name.pdf)

plot(x, y, ...)

dev.off()
```