# R freezes while trying to plot on a mac

Tags: r, macos

Everything was working fine until an update was pushed to OS X (El Capitan) a couple of days ago. Other commands work fine, but 
RStudio started freezing while plotting, so I tried R. Same thing. At least I saw the spinning rainbow wheel with R.app.

I updated R from CRAN, then from AT&T nightly build (as per [R freezes / hangs in Mac OS X Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155623/r-freezes-hangs-in-mac-os-x-yosemite)). I updated/re-installed XQuartz, but still unresponsive RStudio and R while plotting.

I couldn't see anything in the RStudio log file

I also tried deleting .rhistory and other files I could find.

I tried base r `plot` command as well as `ggplot`

My `R.version` output

```
$platform

[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "darwin13.4.0"

$system
[1] "x86_64, darwin13.4.0"

$status
[1] "RC"

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "3.0"

$year
[1] "2016"

$month
[1] "05"

$day
[1] "01"

$`svn rev`
[1] "70572"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.3.0 RC (2016-05-01 r70572)"

$nickname
[1] "Supposedly Educational"

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 RC (2016-05-01 r70572)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try going to tools on the Menu bar and click on update packages, to see what shows up. If there are a ton of them that seem out of date, go through one or two at a time and update them, i just do this by hand in the console, to make sure that you set `dependencies = TRUE`...but you could use the auto updater if you prefer.

Then completely restart the computer, not just R, the whole thing. Once you have done that, try placing the command `gc()` just before your plot begins in your script. This will clear out anything lingering in memory that might be slowing you down.

If, after all that, you are error coding, copy the error and post it in here. It would help.

My experience has been that system updates just mess with things making re-installs of many libraries necessary...but it could be a legitimate bug too. Try a global update and then post an update in here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There were no packages to update, but I moved   packages from my old version to the new version. Did another check for update. No updates. But magically, now, `plot` and `ggplot` both work. Weird.

Comment: Yeah...sometimes it is a matter of packages conflicting in some arcane way with a small change in R. More likely than not it was a dependency. It took me along time to realize that I needed to use `install.packages( , dependencies=TRUE) even on updates.

Comment: coincidentally I just had the a similar problem at home after posting this. It was the Rcpp package. It seems that it is out of date and when installing was not allowing itself to be moved from the temp file to the final destination. I tried a few different ways...it managed to install all of the dependencies, so in the end, I followed the prompts from the warnings to find the  zipped package and just extracted it to my library file. Now ggplot is happy again.

Comment: I think the default dependencies value for `install.packages()` has been changed in recent versions on hte Mac to TRUE, However teh value for checkBuilt remains FALSE and should be set to TRUE when changing R versions.