# Neither R nor RStudio will execute any plot

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

This issue suddenly happened without any obvious reason. R nor RStudio will execute any type of plot be it ggplot or a simple hist(). Nothing comes up in the plot viewer window and the console continually runs the code until I hit stop and the applications crash. This happens in R and RStudio.

I tried running ggplot code that had run perfectly fine previously. Now, whenever I go to plot it continually runs in the console and nothing shows up in the plot view. It will run until I hit stop and the application crashes. I thought it may be an RStudio issue so I removed it and reinstalled and nothing changed. I attempted to run simple plots (e.g. hist()) and the same issue. I then went to regular R and tried to run hist() and the same thing happened. I deleted and reinstalled both R and RStudio and still the issue persists.

Example code that will not execute a plot:

```
v <-  c(9,13,21,8,36,22,12,41,31,33,19) 
hist(v)
```

Comment: Please show us the simplest code you can make that has this problem.  Also can you do other things besides this, like math or simple functions? Is it only graphs that are causing issues?

Please paste your code don't make a screen shot.  Also what do you mean by "regular R"?

Comment: Regular R means R, not RStudio. The original R application. I have updated the post with code.

Comment: This is almost certainly platform and version dependent.  What OS are you using?  What version of it and of R?

Comment: I am on a Mac running Monterey v.12.2.1. R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)

Comment: So you click on an icon with an R and go into a little GUI?  Or you type R at a command line and go into a text environment?

Comment: I apologize, I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Can you try `capabilities()` and share the result?

Comment: My question is when you are starting R outside of RStudio how are you doing it.  Saying whether you are Windows, Mac, Linux will help a lot too.

Comment: jpeg TRUE
png TRUE
tiff TRUE
tcltk TRUE
X11 TRUE
aqua TRUE
http/ftp TRUE
sockets TRUE
libxml FALSE
fifo TRUE
cledit TRUE
iconv TRUE
NLS TRUE
Rprof TRUE
profmem TRUE
cairo TRUE
ICU TRUE
long.double FALSE
libcurl TRUE

Comment: I am on a Mac with Monterey v.12.2.1. When I open R I go to my applications and double click the R icon. RStudio is pinned to my dock and I open it from there.

Comment: This might be related to what you're experiencing (outdated package(s) crashing RStudio on MacOS): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038537/r-freezes-while-trying-to-plot-on-a-mac

Comment: Thank you, that describes exactly what is going on but there were no updates (OS or RStudio) before this started happening. Unfortunately, all my packages are up to date and I do not know how to move "packages from my old version to the new version". The issue still persists. I  had also restarted the computer after various stages in installing and reinstalling both R and RStudio.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by changing the graphics device to AGG. Global options -> general -> graphics -> backend = AGG

Comment: Glad you found a workaround. Problems like this can be mystifying.

Answer (score 0):

I always try this when I get these type of issues:

```
dev.off()
```

Then make a simple plot to see if it's fixed:

```
plot(rnorm(50), rnorm(50))
```