# R crashes when saving a file mac OSX Sierra

Tags: r

Any time I try to save an image file, and lately any file at all, R crashes. I'm on Mac OS X Sierra version 10.12.6, R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"

Anyone else have the same problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have this intermittent issue and have experienced it for over a year, on more that one machine, on El Capitan and Sierra and with multiple versions of R.

There are some helpful suggestions here, but no solution. [R freezes / hangs in Mac OS X Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155623/r-freezes-hangs-in-mac-os-x-yosemite)

I find it crashes less if I save to the default location with the default name and rename the file afterwards.